# How to add a custom implicit conversion to a C++ type in Boost::Python?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

In my C++ code I have a class Foo with many methods taking a Bar type variable as an argument:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void do_this(Bar b);
  void do_that(Bar b);
  /* ... */
};
```

Bar has a number of constructors that create a new object from many common types such as int, std::string, float, etc:

```
class Bar {
public:
  Bar(int i);
  Bar(float f);
  Bar(std::string s);
  /* ... */
};
```

I wrapped this with Boost::Python and I'm now able to call my Foo methods using Python literals directly, as they get implicitly converted to Bar objects.

```
f = Foo()
f.do_this(5)
f.do_that("hello")
```

Now, I would like to be able to use also other Python types, such as tuples, like this:

```
f.do_that((1,2,3))
```

But I don't want to touch the original Bar definition, and I don't want to pollute my C++ library with Boost::Python stuff. I want to write a wrapper function in my binding code, but I just can't understand if this is possible and what is the correct way for doing this.

In other words: can I register a factory function to be used as an automatic conversion in Python?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass Bar near the wrapper code and give your subclass a ctor that takes a bp::object (or a more specific python type)

```
struct Bar_wrapper:Bar,bp::wrapper<Bar>
{
    Bar_wrapper(bp::object arg)
    {
        //code to build a Bar_wrapper Here
    }
}
```

Then export a Bar_wrapper to python instead of a Bar, and call it a Bar as the python name:

```
class<Bar_wrapper>("Bar")
    ...
    .def(init<bp::object>())
    ...
```

Comment: Just to make sure: you would then add the new overloads accepting other Python types in Bar_wrapper, right?

Comment: bp::object covers everything, including int and str. Put the .def's for more specific types first. Other then that yes, overload the ctor with whatever types you feel like.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new constructor `template <typename T> Bar(T)`
in your header and implement as `template <>
Bar::Bar(Tupple) {}`

Comment: UncleZeiv mentioned in the question that he didn't want modify Bar. It's not exactly clear why you're challenging that.

Answer (score 0):

Create some type TupleCollector with overridden "operator ,(int)" so you can write

```
f.do_that((TuppleCollector(), 1, 2, 3))
```

at last create conversion between TupleCollector and expected target

Comment: thank you, this is an interesting idea, but not what I'm looking for... I would like to use tuples directly. I managed to create a new constructor for Bar accepting tuples, but there's no implicit conversion going on, I have to write Bar((1,2,3)) explicitly. :|

Comment: Derive from tuples class and make any assignment of int you want. (operator, - is also applicable)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static factory method and then expose it as one of the Python constructors for the class.  Just make a converter that will take any Python object and you're free do do whatever your please.

```
using namespace boost::python;

Bar CreateBar(object obj)
{
    // Do your thing here

    return Bar;
}

// ..................

class_<Bar>("Bar")
    // .....................
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(&CreateBar))
    //.............
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register from-python converter which will construct `Bar` instance from arbitrary object. See [here](http://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/how-to-write-boost-python-converters/) and an exmaple of my own (converts either `(Vector3,Quaternion)` tuple or 7*double-tuple to 3d transformation `Se3`) [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+junk/tr2/view/head:/py/wrapper/customConverters.cpp#L76).

Note that the logic has two steps, first you determine whether the object is convertible (`convertible`; in your case, you check that it is a sequence, and has the right number of elements), then the `construct` method is called, which actually returns the instance, allocated with the pointer passed as parameter.

The converter must then be registered in `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`. Since the converter registry is global, once registered, it will be subsequently used automatically everywhere. All function argument of type `Bar` or `const Bar&` should be handled just fine (nor sure about `Bar&` from the top of my head).

Answer (score -1):

You can export function do_that which take boost::python::object param, check if param is a python tuple, extract data and pass it to object.